# Windows Phone 7 Facebook Image Posting Issue

Tags: facebook, image, windows-phone-7

I know these facebook api stuffs are really became a pain in the ass, after from my longer searches on internet, I could only find a message post API to facebook. I just want to modify it for both message and image posting. Here is relevant code which posts a message to facebook.(Windows Phone 7)

```
private void PostToWall_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtMessage.Text))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Enter message.");
            return;
        }

        var fb = new FacebookClient(_accessToken);

        fb.PostCompleted += (o, args) =>
        {
            if (args.Error != null)
            {
                Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() => MessageBox.Show(args.Error.Message));
                return;
            }

            var result = (IDictionary<string, object>)args.GetResultData();
            _lastMessageId = (string)result["id"];

            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Message Posted successfully");

                txtMessage.Text = string.Empty;
                btnDeleteLastMessage.IsEnabled = true;
            });
        };

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        parameters["message"] = txtMessage.Text;

        fb.PostAsync("me/feed", parameters);
    }
```

and I have also found a image post code, but I could not integrate it into my code. I think methods are not appropriate with each other.

Here is image post code;

```
   var photo = new WriteableBitmap(0, 0).FromResource("Background200x200.jpg");

  FacebookClient app = new FacebookClient();
  IDictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
  parameters["access_token"] = _facebookAccessToken; //set in another method where I authenticate...
  parameters["name"] = "my picture";
  parameters["message"] = "this is a picture uploaded from my the facebook sdk";
  var mediaObject = new FacebookMediaObject {
    FileName = "Background200x200.jpg",
    ContentType = "image/jpeg",
  };
  mediaObject.SetValue(photo.ToByteArray());
  parameters["source"] = mediaObject;

  app.ApiAsync(
      UploadComplete,
      null,
      "https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed",
      parameters,
      HttpMethod.Post);
```

I just want to post an image with a message. And If you can give me a sample link which posts an image to facebook (I ve been seeking for a ready-coded image post application,that is, Visual studio solution file which I can compile it and XAP it, and run on my phone)

or If you can help me to evolve my message poster to image poster, I would be really pleasured.

THANKS